# Smalltalk: what's the difference between "&" and "and:"

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I just started learning Smalltalk at uni.

I would like to know the difference between the messages `&` and `and:` (just like `|` and `or:`)

Answer (score 15):

Welcome to Smalltalk! You are asking a good question that points out some subtle differences in expressions that are outside or inside blocks.

The '&' message is a "binary" message so takes only one argument. In this case the argument is expected to be a Boolean or an expression that evaluates to a Boolean. Most importantly for our purposes in this comparison, the expression will *always* be evaluated.

The 'and:' message is a "keyword" message and also takes only one argument. But in this case the argument is expected to be a Block that *if later sent the 'value' message* would return a Boolean. So, for our purposes in this comparison, the Block will *not always* be evaluated. (The difference between the binary and keyword messages does not matter for this question.)

The option to not evaluate the argument allows [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in which knowing the left-hand side often allows us to avoid a (possibly expensive) calculation of the right-hand side. So, if the left ("receiver") is false, there is nothing to be gained by evaluating the right-hand side.

So, consider the following:

```
self cheapFalse & self expensiveTrue. "an expensive way to get false"
self cheapFalse and: [self expensiveTrue]. "a cheap way to get false"
```

Answer (score 9):

One obvious difference is that `and:` is a keyword message thus you can write something like

```
a > b and: [b < c]
```

while with `&` you would need parentheses in this expression:

```
a > b & (b < c)
```

because all the binary messages (`+`, `-`, `>`, `<`, `&`, `|`) have the same precedence.

**More importantly**, `and:` and `or:` expect blocks while `&` and `|` expect values. This means that you can write

```
this shouldRedraw and: [ obj stateChanged ]
```

where `obj stateChanged` will be executed only if `this shouldRedraw` is true. This is useful if you want to optimize your code and avoid computing something which is not needed at the moment.

Comment: You should put "b < c" in a block in you first code example. Also, `shouldCompute` should be changed to `shouldRedraw`.

Comment: Hi @JamesFoster, thank you very much for reviewing my answer!!

Comment: Note that nothing prevents passing a block to a binary message in the language (if you wish, you can create a binary message that expects a block argument). It's just a convention used in the Kernel library.